# Voice to Text API with Language Detection or Confidence Rate?

Tags: api, translation, voice

I am trying to develop an application that needs to detect one of two possible languages from an audio stream and transform the audio to text.

Most Voice to Text APIs require specifying the language before detecting the text. Google Translate website allows for voice to text with language detection, I was wondering if there's any API that allows for language recognition from audio?